# Focus problem with multiple window apps on 3 displays

Tags: display, window-manager

When using 2 external monitors (for a total of 3 displays), I have Chrome (or any other multi-window app) with two windows open on different displays (say display-1 and display-2). When I change focus from a 2nd app from display-3 and click on Chrome on display-1, it changes focus to to this window for a split second, and then immediately switches to Chrome on display-2. When I rotate the whole experiment, the same behavior occurs but with a different display preference, like each display falls somewhere in a set precedence. It doesn't matter whether Stage Manager is enabled, and I can't replicate this behavior with 2 or fewer displays. Does anyone else experience this bug? Any fixes or workarounds?